# Upload multiple images or pdf files

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3

I have to upload multiple images at one time from a form when onsubmit event occurs.How Do i have to do this one.
I am googling around many stackoverflow questions from past 8 hours on my requirement. But i didn't find any answer which suits my question. Please Help Developers.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure about ajax but in simple way try this http://w3code.in/2015/09/upload-file-using-codeigniter/

Comment: Thanks @Ricky,But i need this same process using ajax

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `codeigniter`, but you can post file like following using `ajax`.

```
$("form").on('submit', (function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    var formData = new FormData(this);

    $.ajax({
        url : "/Home/Upload", //you url here
        type : "POST", 
        data : formData,
        cache : false,
        contentType : false,
        processType : false,
        success : function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}));
```

Hope this will help you.